# Get Google account domain in Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

I am using [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people) in my Android app. How can I get the domain of the authenticated user's account? It is not a property on the com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person model.

Specifically I only want people from one company to be able to access the app using their work Google accounts (everyone in the company has one).

I can of course retrieve the email address using `Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);` and could check the domain of the email address, but that seems nasty.

Comment: What do you mean by domain ? be more explicit...

Comment: @MicheleLacorte eg. '@mycompany.com'