# How to check domain of Google Account in my app login screen?

Tags: android, authentication, google-account

I am trying to create a login screen within my android app, and restrict access to the "private" (or password protected) section of the app to users of a specific organization.

Knowing that the organization accounts are all Google Accounts (with either of two domain names (eg. user.name@domain1.com or user.name@domain2.com)), how can I check and only allow users with those two email types to access the app?

I was thinking of checking whether the domain corresponded to either of the ones used by the organization, but I am not quite sure how to go about this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check if the email address string ends with the domains you want!

Comment: @Xenolion ah, ok! I thought it would have been more complicated! That's fine, thanks!

Comment: Okay **Happy Coding!**.

Comment: @Xenolion just saw this now: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470659/)

Comment: Yeah I have seen it looks like it can directly solve your question! Gotcha! Your research earns it all!